# self nessary in setting class instance Var from different class instance Var Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Is the self needed in  `Parser.self.totalEntries`?

```
class Iter(Parser):

def __init__(self, Parser):

    self.totalEntriesI = Parser.self.totalEntries
```

I have given up looking for it in the docs, perhaps I'm just a silly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is : no, you don't need it.

I was trying to make sense of your code here but this part bugged me :

```
def __init__(self, Parser):
```

However, the capital P for parser can be a bit ambiguous : it can mean either the `Parser` class that you inherit from (in which case this parameter is useless), or 'any parser given as parameter' (in which case you might want to lowercase that for clarity).

Assuming you mean a specific given parser, you could rewrite all to have the following:

```
def __init__(self, myLovelyParser):

self.totalEntriesI = myLovelyParser.totalEntries
```

Which is a lot clearer.

The only point of `self` is to give a bound name for the implicit instance parameter. 
More philosophically : "From the outside, there is no `self`"

Answer (score 0):

The `self` parameter (which does not need, but should be called that) is just the same as the object being called on. Now `__init__` is a little bit special, but in general `obj.method(args)` is the same as `cls.method(obj, args)` where `cls` is the class of obj. There's nothing more magical with `self` than it is automatically inserted when calling the method. With `__init__` of course the `self` argument is the object under construction.

In other word the `self` (or first) argument is just the object on which the method has been called.

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to perform (since it is somewhat confusing to have an argument named the same as the class of the method), but `self` is NOT what you would do if you want to access some other object, first of all you have to supply the other object also (for example as an argument) and access it in the same way:

```
def method(self, other):
     self.attr = other.attr
```

Note that `other.self.attr` would require that the object `other` has an attribute called `self` which it normally doesn't. Consequently it is normally incorrect to do that - and in any case it is quite different from `other.attr` anyway.